# Using convention plugin with struts.xml

Tags: java, xml, struts2, struts2-convention-plugin

I'm using [convention plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention) in my project and everything was fine until I needed to add a custom interceptor.

To add a custom interceptor I need to have `struts.xml` in my project. But when I add `struts.xml`, it gives me 404 error for every page.

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029376/using-struts-xml-with-convention-plugin) but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You have not provided enough information to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `struts.xml` configuration file should be in the source folder, such as `src` or `resources`. When you build the application the compiled output directed to `WEB-INF/classes`. You can check this file exists before you deploy or start a server with already deployed web application.

FYI, the [convention plugin](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/convention) doesn't replace the XWork configuration, but extend it with possibility to override. The `struts.xml` is used by the same purpose, but using different configuration provider.

So, configuring interceptors using convention plugin make sure you use the right parent package that contains your custom interceptor.